# How to parse data from an extracted JSON object property using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I have a JSON object property that is a string and looks like this:

```
"&1 *UBIN 8 &2 *UBIN 8 &3 *UBIN 8 &4 *CHAR 10 &5 *UBIN 8 &6 *UBIN 8 &7 *UBIN 8 &8 *CCHAR *VARY 4"
```

I want to parse this property (string) to extract the numbers that have an & (ampersand) in front of them, and place each extracted &number into an array. The result would look like:

```
var array = ['&1', '&2', '&3', '&4', '&5', '&6', '&7', '&8'];
```

I am using AngularJS.

Any suggestions on how to best accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var str="&1 *UBIN 8 &2 *UBIN 8 &3 *UBIN 8 &4 *CHAR 10 &5 *UBIN 8 &6 *UBIN 8 &7 *UBIN 8 &8 *CCHAR *VARY 4";

var result = $.map(str.split(" "), function(element) {
  if ( element.substring(0,1)  == "&") return element;
});
```

result

```
["&1","&2","&3","&4","&5","&6","&7","&8"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm for this would be "split() and filter()".

A naive approach could check if the first character is an ampersand:

```js
input = "&1 *UBIN 8 &2 *UBIN 8 &3 *UBIN 8 &4 *CHAR 10 &5 *UBIN 8 &6 *UBIN 8 &7 *UBIN 8 &8 *CCHAR *VARY 4"

input.split(" ").filter(item => item.startsWith("&"))
```

This works well and is fast, but makes the assumption that only numbers can come after `&`, so it will also return items like `&abc`.

You could also use a regex:

```js
input.split(" ").filter(item => item.match(/^&\d+$/))
```

This is slower, but it's more robust. It also makes the assumption that only full-number items are allowed, so it will reject items like `&12a`.

Both solutions can be adapted if the full list of requirements differ, as from the question is not fully clear if:

- the separator is space, or it can be other characters (e.g. comma, or newline, or tab)
- items starting with `&` are known to contain only numbers, or can contain other characters too
- negative numbers are considered valid or not